# Configure Cute Editor in ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, cuteeditor

I want to load cute editor in ASP.NET MVC 5 project. Is that possible ?

According to this  [Cute Editor Documentation](https://cutesoft.net/developer+guide/index.htm#page=Deployment.htm)   I have been followed every single step of that . but it does not explain how to Configure  Cute Editior for ASP.NET MVC web project view page.

So this is my cshtml view page (HTML page)

```
 <Register TagPrefix="CE" Namespace="CuteEditor" Assembly="CuteEditor">

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4> Edit the Brochure </h4> 


<form runat="server">
    <CE:Editor id="Editor1" runat="server" />
</form>
```

what else I've missed

Comment: you can't mix Razor and WebForms syntax and compopents it's 2 different technologies for View Rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Your using both asp.net server side code and MVC razor view engine in your view .

To implement Cute editor in your MVC  View please folow steps in the link below :

http://richtexteditor.com/deployment/rich-text-editor-aspnet-mvc.aspx

Comment: thanks for the help , but I have integrated this Rich Text editor before its not my choice unfortunately